# Differences between Pjax and AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, pjax

I need to know the following things:

- When should/could use PJAX against AJAX and when shouldn't be
- I'm an ASP MVC Developer and I want to know what's real different between them and if there is no difference so why Microsoft didn't set PJAX helper like AJAX helper for Asp.Net Mvc projects
- and finally how can I have PJAX Form like Ajax Form